# python - groupby multi columns for fillna in one column by Mode

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
user   type age  education phone
1      1    45   1         1
2      1    50   NA        1
3      NA   40   NA        2
4      2    55   2         2
```

fillna in education column by mode

```
df["education"] = pd.to_numeric(df["education"], errors="coerce")

df["education"].fillna(df.groupby(["age", "type", "phone"])["education"].transform(lambda x: pd.Series.mode(x)[0]), inplace=True)
```

IndexError: index out of bounds

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: fillna in education column by using groupby

Comment: post the expected output not this "fillna in education column by using groupby ". You already written this in post.

Comment: from my code, I get error IndexError: index out of bounds